# Is there a way I can put 'but' in an if statement?

Tags: c, cs50

In my CS50 course I am making a program in which encrypts a message depending on the characters entered by the user.

If the user inputs 3 each letter of the message is shifted 3 units right. To do this, I converted these letters into ASCII codes. Unfortunately, when the user tries to encrypt any message with any form of Z, the user is sent back a special character such as parentheses or brackets. This also happens when the original ASCII code plus the key(inputted by the user) is greater 90 or greater than 122. The ASCII code 90 being Z and 122 being z. To solve this, I've put a condition that states when the ASCII code is greater than 90 or 122, subtract the value of key. This of course also doesn't work because when inputting a value such as a with the value of key being 3. For example : when the user inputs ZzAa. Every letter besides a is encrypted to a letter. 'a' on the other hand is encrypted to '^'. The reason being a is 97 in ASCII code and 97 is greater than 90 but not 122 so it gets reduced to 94 which is '^'.

I was wondering if there was a '`but`' condition in the `if` statement so I can put the condition : greater than 90 but less than 97, so that a (`97`) isn't reduced to 94 (`^`)

I've tried putting in a Logical Or and a Logical AND. None of them seemed to work. One example of it not working is when you input 3 as the key and ZzAa as the test message being encrypted.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
   if (argc != 2)
   // If the user uses the program incorrectly, it shows them how to do it and quits the program
   {
       printf("Usage : ./caesar key\n");
       return 1;
   }
   // stores the second value inputted by the user(key) into an integer key
   int key = atoi(argv[1]) % 26;

   char *ptext = get_string("Plaintext : ");

   for (int i = 0, n = strlen(ptext); i < n; i++)
   {
       if(ptext[i] + key >= 90 || ptext[i] >= 122)
       {
           printf("Cipher text: %c\n ", ptext[i] - key);
           printf("Cipher text: %i\n ", ptext[i] - key);
       }
       else
       {
           printf("Cipher text: %c\n ", ptext[i] + key);
           printf("Cipher text: %i\n ", ptext[i] + key);
       }
   }

   return 0;

}


This worked for the most part
```

Comment: In propositional logic, "but" means "and". Your attempt at using a logical and is of the most interest here.

Comment: `printf("Usage : ./caesar key\n"); return 1;` is inconsistent.  If you are printing the message to stdout (and usage messages should be written to stdout), then you should return 0.  If you consider this an error (as indicated by returning 1), then the error message should be written to stderr.  Usage statements are not error messages, so you should `return EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use parenthesis to group mutually-inclusive logical expressions. Your `but` is actually an `and` (`&&`), like so:

```
if( ( ptext[i] + key >= 90 && ptext[i] + key < 97 ) || ptext[i] >= 122 )
{
    // etc
}
```

That said, I would use an intermediate variable so it's immediately clear to the reader what's going on:

```
const char clear   = ptext[i];
const char shifted = ptext[i] + key;

if( ( clear => 90 && clear < 97 ) || shifted >= 122 ) 
{
    // etc
}
```

Or consider introducing named boolean values to make the code self-documenting:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

...

const char clear   = ptext[i];
const char shifted = ptext[i] + key;

const bool isAscii        = clear => 90 && clear < 97;
const bool isOutsideRange = shifted >= 122;

if( isAscii || isOutsideRange ) 
{
    // etc
}
```

(Note that in most programming languages (and pretty much all compiled languages) intermediate variables do not hurt performance at all because compilers are smart enough to know they don't change the actual behaviour of a function at all. Sometimes they can even make a program faster because the compiler can infer more about your intent).